# ECDSA key fingerprint - looks like it is base64 encoded, but too few characters

Tags: git, ssh-keys, gitlab

I've setup a [GitLab VM](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/gitlab), and have created a project on it. Now I'm trying to connect to it from another machine using my git client ([Git for Windows](http://gitforwindows.org/) v2.7.1...also tried upgrading to latest version which is 2.15.1, but no change).

On the Windows machine, I try:

```
git push -u origin --all
The authenticity of host 'localgit.local (10.1.2.3)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:twmcV7LjBtI9vUsDeFEHeH0lUcBAihWtGye0K9vHCrk.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
```

I chose "no" because when I went to double check that on the VM, I found a different fingerprint:

```
ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
256 7e:e4:4e:7f:47:b0:41:75:2c:45:bd:be:f5:44:77:d7 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub (ECDSA)
```

Ok, it's in hex format, so I'll just convert that to base64, right?

```
hex: 7ee44e7f47b041752c45bdbef54477d7
base64: fuROf0ewQXUsRb2+9UR31w==
```

Well that doesn't match...what if I go the other way and convert that base64 fingerprint to hex and see what it looks like? Turns out I cannot, it is 43 characters, and a base64 string must have a length that is a multiple of 4.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Crossdupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37019/how-to-verify-a-severs-ecdsa-fingerprint-during-ssh/37036#37036 (mine) and https://superuser.com/questions/421997/what-is-a-ssh-key-fingerprint-and-how-is-it-generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The octets-separated-by-colons format is an MD5 fingerprint, not a SHA256 fingerprint.  You can't directly convert one to the other (well, you kinda could, perhaps, if you reverse the MD5 fingerprint, but that still takes a bit of CPU power).

That `ssh-keygen` is outputting an MD5 fingerprint suggests that that machine may be running a rather old version of OpenSSH, because the default output format these days is SHA256.  You can try passing `-E sha256` to `ssh-keygen` to get it to output a SHA256 hash, in case there's a version that supported SHA256 but defaulted to MD5, and you happen to be running it, but I wouldn't want to say it'll work for sure.

If you can't get your version of `ssh-keygen` to output SHA256, the other option is to "downgrade" the SSH client to output an MD5 fingerprint on connection.  For that, you need to set `-o FingerprintHash=md5` on the command line (or `FingerprintHash md5` in the SSH config).  Exactly how best to do that, given you're running SSH via git, is left as an exercise for the astute reader.  <grin>

Sidebar: the reason why the base64 SHA256 hash isn't the "right" number of characters is because a SHA256 hash isn't the "right" number of characters to fit into a base64 string without some trailing `=` signs.  Since the last few characters will "always" be `=` signs, they just get dropped, which saves a couple of useless characters.

Comment: Reversing either hash wouldn't work - even if you had the computing power to do so. The preimage is unlikely to be unique and if you get a different preimage then the other hash would be wrong. A much better way to know if the two hashes match would be for the warning from the ssh client to display both hashes. Not sure if such a feature exist, but in principle it would be an easy feature to implement.

Comment: Well, ssh-keygen has no version parameter, doesn't seem to like that -E option either, so I checked and the OpenSSH version I have on that VM is "OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016". I'll try updating things an see if that lets me get a sha256 hash.

Comment: Never mind about upgrading - apparently that's a whole other rabbit hole. I figured out how to get the sha256 hash value on the server side so I can verify it matches what the client sees. You were right, the client isn't padding it with equals signs. `sed "s/.* \(.*\) .*/\1/g" /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub | base64 --decode | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl base64` produced `twmcV7LjBtI9vUsDeFEHeH0lUcBAihWtGye0K9vHCrk=`

Comment: @kasperd hey, I said "perhaps"!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, so I dug little bit deeper.

On the linux server, you can run

```
awk '{print $2}' /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub | base64 -d | sha256sum -b | sed 's/ .*$//' | xxd -r -p | base64
```

to generate the same `SHA256+Base64` fingerprint that shows up when your client tries to connect.

Source:
https://www.lastbreach.com/blog/ssh-public-key-verification-with-fingerprinthash